# Forecasting with C-Vine Copula

Tags: time-series, correlation

I have a dataset with 4 different variables: x1, x2, x3 and k1. I'd like to use C-Vine copula to model interdependency btw these 4 variables with k1 being root node, then make forecasting of k_{t+1}. I've read several articles but could not find a way. Do you have any suggestions for me?

Note: By the way, I also tried to use RVineStructureSelect in RStudio, but cannot define the root node, this is automatically selected.

Answer (score 0):

`RVineStructureSelect` selects the vine class automatically, based on the Kendall's tau values. To make a C-vine choice, you should make the function argument `type = 1`. Then this will returns you the C-vine structure but maybe with another root node than `K1`. To make a C-vine structure with a root node `k1`, then you should do this manually, then, you cannot use the `RvineStructureSelect` function. Instead you can use `RvineCopulaSelect` or `RVineSequentialEst`.